# How to get an indication that Pytest parameter has been changed

Tags: pytest

I have a class with multiple tests in it, the class has two parameterizations.
If a particular parameter has changed, I need to revert the machine on which the test ran to its previous state.

Note: I can't use "machine" as one of the test parameters, lets assume it is an external configuration and this class knows how to run on requested "machine" (internal infrastructure limitation)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1), scope='class')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('browser', BROWSERS, ids=[browser.name for browser in BROWSERS], 
indirect=True)
class ClassTest:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def revert_machine:
        if browser changed:  <------- how to catch if browser has been changed?
            do revert machine  <-------

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_a')
    def test_a(self):
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_ams_attack_onset', depends=['test_a'])
    def test_a(self):
        assert True
```

How do I catch if browser has been changed?

I've tried classic last/current comparison but a global variable is required for storing LAST_BROWSER, I am looking for more elegant/pytest solution?

collection order:

```
<Package acceptance>
  <Module test_foo.py>
    <Class ClassTest>
      <Function test_open_browser[chrome-1]>
      <Function test_close_browser[chrome-1]>
      <Function test_open_browser[ff-1]>
      <Function test_close_browser[ff-1]>
```

Comment: I wonder how you got this code to run, since there a several errors in it: ClassTest is not collected by pytest, the functions are missing iteration parameter ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [fixture parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize)

```
import pytest


BROWSERS = ["chrome", "ff"]
ITERATIONS = 2


@pytest.fixture(params=BROWSERS, autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    browser_ = request.param

    yield browser_

    # revert_machine()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1), scope='class')
class Test:

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_a')
    def test_a(self, iteration):
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name='test_ams_attack_onset', depends=['test_a'])
    def test_a(self, iteration):
        assert True
```